# Яндекс карты(api 2.1), по нажатию на блок, удалить поиск карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как по нажатию на блок удалить поиск в яндекс карте (api 2.1), подозреваю что `myMap.controls.remove()`; но что тогда передавать в `remove`?

Код инициализации карты:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
  // Создание экземпляра карты
  var myMap;
  var myCollection;
  var myPlacemark;
  var mySearchControl;
// skipped
  function createMap (state) {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('shops__map', state);
    var mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
      options: {
        noPlacemark: true
      }
    });
    myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
// skipped
    $('.remove-search').on('click',function(e){
        myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если контрол стандартный (вы его под дугим ключем не добавляли), тогда так:

```
myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
```

**Дополнено**

Поскольку вы добавляете контрол не по ключу

```
var mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl(...);
myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
```

то и удалять вы должны именно тот объект, который добавили (или предварительно выяснить его ключ)

```
myMap.controls.remove(mySearchControl);
```

см. также

- [control.Manager.remove()](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Manager-docpage/#remove)
- [ключи предустановленных контролов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Manager-docpage/#add)

PS. Кстати вместо

```
var mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: { noPlacemark: true }
});
myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
```

можно было бы написать

```
myMap.controls.add('searchControl', { noPlacemark: true });
```

и удалять контрол по ключу

Comment: пробывал, но чет не удаляет(((

Comment: Покажите код инициализации карты. И посмотрите, нету-ли ошибки в JS-консоли. Что-то мне кажется, что в вашем обработчике клика недоступна переменная `myMap`

Comment: вот https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/ronsafff/

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, я запихиваю в переменную по тому что надо потом с ней работать дальше.